# What does a negative "confirmations" value in listtransactions mean?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, json-rpc, confirmations

I sent a transaction on a small altcoin, and running `listtransactions` an hour later or so says `-1` confirmations. It is forked from Bitcoin Core 0.8 and barely modified. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

-1 means not in local mempool and not in a block

Comment: I ended up resolving this by running a `-rescan`, which made the transaction disappear from the mempool, which would imply that it was ONLY in the local mempool...so are you sure about this?